# Envio de formulário PHP

Tags: php

Eu possuo um formulário onde os campos `name=""` tem uns valores diferente entre `[ ]` por causa de uma API que estou utilizando. Eu queria saber como posso pegar esse valor do *input* para enviar para um e-mail?

```
<form id="msform" method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="nome_completo" name="curriculo[nome_completo]" minlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo*">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer com JavaScript e pegar o value:

```js
function getFormSubmitValues(formId){ 
     document.getElementById(formId).addEventListener('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     const queryMyInput = document.querySelectorAll("#" + document.getElementById(formId).id + ' input');
  queryMyInput.forEach(function(n){
      //return n.value;
      console.log(n.value);
  });
 });
}

getFormSubmitValues('msform');
```

```html
<form id="msform" method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="nome_completo2" name="curriculo1[nome_completo]" minlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo*">
 <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Depois de pegar esse value, pode talvez depois, usar Ajax pra enviar  o formulário! Se não souber como usa, eu posso editar a resposta mais tarde e te explicar.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer com o Ajax, mas como eu tenho um campo de upload eu não soube fazer o envio do formulario junto com o upload por email usando $("#enviar").click(function(){